# Running Wagtail site with Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, wagtail

I'm trying to convert an existing Wagtail site to run with Docker. I have created the image and then run the container, but I'm unable to connect in the browser window. Getting `0.0.0.0 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements/base.txt

RUN mkdir -p -m 700 /app/static
RUN mkdir -p -m 700 /app/media

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.dev DJANGO_DEBUG=on
ENV SECRET_KEY=notsosecretkey
ENV DATABASE_URL=postgres://none
ENV SENDGRID_KEY=sendgridkey

EXPOSE 8080

RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh \
    && chmod +x /app/start-app.sh

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/app/start-app.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: app_db
      POSTGRES_USER: app_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  app:
    container_name: mysite_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://app_user:changeme@db/app_db
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec "$@"
```

start-app.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

dev.py settings file:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

for template_engine in TEMPLATES:
    template_engine['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    '0.0.0.0',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': db_cache_url.config('DATABASE_URL', extra={'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'NAME': 'mysite', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'PORT': '5432'}),
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I run `docker run -p 8080:8080 app:latest` and it works when I run `docker ps` showing that it's at `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`, but when I go to `0.0.0.0:8080` in the browser window, I get the error. If I remove the `DATABASES` setting, I see Django errors loading, but then I'm getting `settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.` so I think it needs to be there. What am I missing?

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1:8080 in your browser instead of 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I've tried `localhost:8080`, `127.0.0.1:8080` and `0.0.0.0:8080` and all get the same error in the browser.

Comment: can you connect to :8080 within the container itself?

Comment: @ajankuv I'm not sure what command I'd need to run to check this.

Comment: exec into the container, curl localhost:8080